# Can someone help me check this code pls

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error and I dont know where the problem is:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `dp_confirms` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`newuser` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newpass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`newanswer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`newmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`newfname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newlname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newcompany` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '', 
`newregnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newdrvnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newaddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '', 
`newcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
`newcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '', 
`newstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newzip` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
`newphone` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
`newfax` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
`sponsor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', 
`confirm` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,[...])

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
  K' at line 22
```

Here is the main code.

```
-- 
    -- Table structure for table `dp_cards`
    -- 

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dp_cards`;
    CREATE TABLE `dp_cards` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `owner` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `ctype` varchar(8) NOT NULL default '',
      `cname` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
      `cnumber` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `ccvv` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
      `cmonth` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      `cyear` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    -- 
    -- Table structure for table `dp_confirms`
    -- 

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dp_confirms`;
    CREATE TABLE `dp_confirms` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `newuser` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newpass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `newanswer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `newmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `newfname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newlname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newcompany` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
      `newregnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newdrvnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newaddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
      `newcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
      `newcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
      `newstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newzip` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `newphone` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
      `newfax` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
      `sponsor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `confirm` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
      KEY `newmail` (`newmail`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: the queries are fine, how are you executing them?

Comment: i have run this query through phpmyadmin query run successfully

Answer (score 6):

I believe `TIMESTAMP` fields don't take a size.  Remove the (14)

Comment: Here is what i got after removing time stamp #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
  KEY' at line 22

Comment: Remove the parenthesis completely.  `cdate timestamp NOT NULL`...

Comment: Thanks a million...worked perfectly